# Delphi XE5 datasnap server getting LAN IP?

Tags: delphi, routes, nat, datasnap

I'm starting some testing with DataSnap.

I'm trying to create a simple server using the wizard of the new server, the server is created successfully.

Using the component DSTCPServerTransport1 OnConnect event I put the following code:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSTCPServerTransport1Connect(
  Event: TDSTCPConnectEventObject);
begin
  showmessage('Hello World!');
end;
```

the problem is that I am behind a router ("dlink 2750b").

1: already configured a virtual server on the router 
[image]

2: I've tried port forwarding on the router
[image]

3: I've tried to create a DMZ host on the router
[image]

but the DataSnap server only accepts connections from network (192.168.1.77 is my server) not from external 177.102.148.80
[image]

**Strange thing happens** if I access the site http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and try to check the port 211 DataSnap server OnConnect triggers the event and displays the message 'Hello World!'
[image]

immediately when I press the "Check" button 
OnConnect triggers the event and displays the message ("Hello World!")

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: You mentioned 3 steps on the router, is it possible you've somehow set things up that are conflicting? Try simplifying your router configuration so that it's just forwarding port 211 from <any> interface to 192.168.1.177.

Comment: *I'm starting some testing with DataSnap.* if you're just starting that is a goot time to read http://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests-part-2/